# Custom middleware returning redirect loop

Tags: python, django

I have referred to the code shared on this website http://onecreativeblog.com/post/59051248/django-login-required-middleware

to make a login required middleware. The problem is it is running into redirect loop.

```
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout

EXEMPT_URLS = [re.compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [re.compile(url) for url in 
    settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:

def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response

def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    assert hasattr(request, 'user')
    path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')

    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        if not any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS):
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

I have looked into stackoverflow and tried almost every solution but in vain.
Settings url

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/blog/index/'

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS= (
    r'^blog/signup/$',
    r'^blog/logout/$',
)
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: It is running into a redirect loop.

Comment: `LoginRequiredMiddleware`? if you're using classes you can just use the `LoginRequiredMixin` or `PermissionRequiredMixin`. I don't know why you're in need of your own class?

Comment: What is `settings.LOGIN_URL`? Which version of Django are you using? What is `settings.MIDDLEWARE`?

Comment: @KingReload I know I can but I am experimenting with middleware and trying to learn about it.

Comment: @Alasdair I think I got a fix around to the above problem. There was a problem with my LOGIN_URL in settings.(The format of the url was not correct). It's fixed now. Thanks